# F# Applying Map.filter on Map derived from list of records

Tags: f#

I have these records:

```
type Name        = string
type PhoneNumber = int
type Sex         = Male | Female
type YearOfBirth = int
type Interests   = string list
type Client      = {name: Name; phone: PhoneNumber; sex: Sex; birth: YearOfBirth; interests: Interests}

let client1 = {name = "Jon"; phone = 37613498; sex = Male; birth = 1980; interests = ["Cars"; "Boats"; "Airplanes"]}
let client2 = {name = "Jonna"; phone = 31852654; sex = Female; birth = 1970; interests = ["Makeup"; "Sewing"; "Bananas"]}
```

Which I put into a list:

```
let file1 = [client1;client2]
```

I then attempt to create a function using `Map` which should be able to filter `file1` and only return the client, which has the same birthday as the one given in the function.

Example:

```
requestMap 1980
```

Would return `map [("Jon", (37613498, Male, 1980, ["Cars"; "Boats"; "Airplanes"]))]` in this case.

I've stumbled into a function, but I've got a bit stuck now.

```
let requestMap yob =
    Map.ofList [for f in file1 do yield f.name,(f.phone,f.sex,f.birth,f.interests)] |>
    Map.filter (fun key value -> )
```

I have trouble figuring out how I can get to `birth` in the current map's `value`? Because as it is right now, it's hidden inside `value` which is a `PhoneNumber * Sex * YearOfBirth * Interests` tuple currently.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access elements of a tuple, you can use pattern matching:

```
Map.filter (fun key (phone, sex, birth, interests) -> birth = yob)
```

Or, if you're not interested in anything except birth year, you can ignore all other fields using underscore:

```
Map.filter (fun _ (_, _, birth, _) -> birth = yob)
```

That said, I would recommend filtering first and creating the map after, this would be less expensive:

```
let requestMap yob = 
    file1 
    |> List.filter (fun x -> x.birth = yob)
    |> List.map (fun f -> f.name,(f.phone,f.sex,f.birth,f.interests))
    |> Map.ofList
```

And while we're on the subject: why do you need to create that huge tuple in the first place? Can't you make the original records be values in your map? Like this:

```
let requestMap yob = 
    file1 
    |> List.filter (fun x -> x.birth = yob)
    |> List.map (fun f -> f.name, f)
    |> Map.ofList
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some more options not mentioned in other answers:

Store the whole `Client` in the Map value:

```
[for f in file1 do yield f.name, f]
|> Map.ofList
|> Map.filter (fun _ f -> f.birth = yob)
```

Do a conditional `yield` with an `if`:

```
[ for f in file1 do
    if f.birth = yob then
        yield f.name, f ]
|> Map.ofList
```

Comment: In your first example, wouldn't it be better to filter before mapping?

Comment: @TaoGómezGil Probably, assuming that it's cheaper to make an intermediate list than an intermediate map, but I was trying to stay close to the initial code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to filter the `file1` list before transforming it into a map rather than creating the map and then filtering it.

```
let requestMap yob =
let filtered =
    List.filter (fun client ->
      match client with
      | { Client.birth = year } when year = yob -> true
      | _ -> false) file1
Map.ofList [for f in filtered do yield f.name,(f.phone,f.sex,f.birth,f.interests)]
```

Comment: This is an unnecessarily overcomplicated body of the filtering function. Could be just `fun client -> client.birth = yob`

Comment: I made the undocumented assumption that the asker would probably want to filter by other record fields in the future. I think pattern matching would be more helpful in that case.

However, for only filtering by client.birth, I agree the filter I proposed it a little much.

Comment: This option to filter by something else absolutely doesn't warrant this syntax. If you later decide to filter by, say, sex, you could just add `|| client.sex = s`. Still no need for a `match ... with` expression.

Comment: I see your point. In my mind, pattern matching is more useful for decomposing structured data and looking at the decomposed values rather than performing simple value comparisons. This question is definitely more about simple value comparisons.